# BWK's C Tutorial - while(putchar(getchar()) != EOF) ignores EOF

Tags: c

I'm reading [Programming in C - A Tutorial](http://cm.bell-labs.co/who/dmr/ctut.pdf) by Brian Kernighan and on page 5 he suggests that

```
main( ) {
    char c;
    while( (c=getchar( )) != ′\0′ )
        putchar(c);
}
```

can be simplified to

```
main( ) {
    while( putchar(getchar( )) != ′\0′ ) ;
}
```

with the only difference being that the last `'\0'` is printed in the 2nd one.

However, when I compile this, replacing `'\0'` with `EOF`, and pass a string: `$ printf "abc" | ./a.out`, the program goes into an infinite loop printing ASCII `0xff` characters.

If I change it to `while( putchar(getchar( )) != 'd' ) ;` and run `$ printf "abcde" | ./a.out`, it successfully prints up to and including `d` and then exits.

Why does it go into an endless loop instead of printing `abc(EOF)` and exiting?

Comment: Dude - "EOF" <> "\0'!  If you look in stdio.h, you'll see it's "-1".  Q: Does everything work if you just copy the examples verbatim?

Comment: I tried it with both '\0' and -1 (no quotes). As soon as it hits EOF (^D, end of file descriptior, end of string, etc), it starts spamming 0xff.

Comment: Alternative code: `int main( ) { int c; while( (c=getchar( )) != EOF )  putchar(c); } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EOF is a macro with a negative value that is implementation dependent (very commonly -1). If you check out man page for [putchar(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/putchar) you can read that `putchar()` writes the character provided as argument, cast to an unsigned char to stdout and returns the character written as an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on error.

When `getchar()` returns EOF at the end of the stdin, `putchar()` casts this value to unsigned char, writes it to the stdout and returns the unsigned char value cast to an int. Therefore if EOF is for example equal to -1, `putchar()` in your example will return 255 (-1 cast to unsigned char, then cast to int). If you replaced '\0' with EOF in the while loop, you will get an infinite loop because 255 != EOF.

Answer (score 3):

According to [§7.21.7.8 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.8), the function `putchar` will convert its `int` argument to an `unsigned char` and write that character, and also return that character (not the original unconverted `int` argument).

Calling `putchar( EOF )` will therefore return `(unsigned char)EOF`, which cannot be equal to `EOF` (because `EOF` is required to be a negative value).

For this reason, in the line

```
while( putchar( getchar() ) != EOF )
```

the loop condition will always be true, so that you will have an infinite loop.

Note that `EOF` is not an actual character, but simply a special macro constant to indicate an error or end-of-file condition.

Comment: I think this finally explains it.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very old tutorial; you can tell because it doesn't specify a return type for `main`.  But the real problem with it is that it loops until `getchar` returns 0 (also known as `'\0'`), but in fact `getchar` will return `EOF` at the end of the file, and that is equal to `-1` on my system (and possibly yours too).

Apparently, back when that tutorial was written `getchar` would return 0 at the end of the file.  That was not very good behavior though, because it makes it tricky to process binary data, which usually contains many 0 bytes.  At some point the language was changed, and `getchar` was changed to return an `int` instead of a `char`, and to return `EOF` at the end of the file.

Comment: There is a secondary problem:  putchar(getchar()) != EOF only happens if putchar() hits an error -- otherwise it masks its argument down to a character size, so when getchar() returns `-1`, putchar() returns 0xff.

Comment: @mevets That fixed it! I checked `!= 0xff` and it printed a single 0xff and quit.

Comment: That didn't fix it; that is the bug; and is why the program *has* to be: `int c; while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) putchar(c);`  Note the `int` and the purposeful avoidance of printing a `0xff`.

Comment: I'm guessing there's no way to just print a clean EOF instead of 0xff using this nested expression, then.

Comment: `EOF` is not a character (unlike `DOS, CPM` systems where `^Z` marked `EOF`).   EOF is a condition of the data source you are reading from.   When it is a file, it is because you have already read the file.  When it is a `tty`-like device, it is when the user enters a character that the device-management software interprets as and end-of-input.   In `unix` derived systems, that defaults to `^D`, but can be set to any character via `stty` or `tcsetattr`.